# PHP - error when joining fields from different SQL databases

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, select, join

I am trying to build a query where I return results from 3 different tables as per the following:

**Events Table**  DateTime, Direction, DeviceName

**Tenants** TenantName

**Individuals** FirstName, LastName

Initially I've returned fields from the first 2 tables with the following SQL:

```
SELECT EventTime, DeviceName, Comment, TenantName
FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event 
     INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants 
       ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
WHERE taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime 
       BETWEEN '01/04/2014 16:00:00' AND '01/04/2014 16:00:59
```

I've joined both the Event and Tenants tables using the **TenantId** Field.

I then needed to also return the fields **FirstName** and **LastName** (from the Individuals table), so I tried using the sql below:

```
    SELECT EventTime, DeviceName, Comment, TenantName, FirstName, LastName 
    FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event 
    INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants 
       ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
    INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants
       ON inet.dbo.Tenants.TenantId = inet.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
    WHERE taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime 
          BETWEEN '01/04/2014 16:00:00' AND '01/04/2014 16:00:59'
```

However this returned the following error:

> The objects "InetDb.dbo.Tenants" and "InetDb.dbo.Tenants" in the FROM
>   clause have the same exposed names. Use correlation names to
>   distinguish them.

Can someone please guide me on how it's best to resolve this please ?

**UPDATED**

I've modified the syntax to the below:

```
SELECT EventTime, DeviceName, Comment, TenantName, FirstName, LastName 
FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event 
INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants 
    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Individuals
    ON  InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
WHERE taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime 
      BETWEEN '01/04/2014 16:00:00' AND '01/04/2014 16:00:59'
```

I then received the following error:

> Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ambiguous column name 'FirstName'.
>   Msg 209, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Ambiguous column name 'LastName'

Comment: INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants T
       ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = T.TenantId
    INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants TT
       ON TT.TenantId = inet.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx

Comment: where is the inet.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx table in the join

Comment: @joebegborg07:- you are using sometime InetDb.dbo.Individuals and inet.dbo.Individuals????? which one is correct?   And same with  InetDb.dbo.Tenants and inet.dbo.Tenants?????  USE the correct qualifier name for table...and you are good to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `Individuals` table in INNER JOIN and use `Tenants` by mistake.

```
SELECT EventTime, DeviceName, Comment, TenantName,        
       InetDb.dbo.Individuals.FirstName, InetDb.dbo.Individuals.LastName 
FROM taclogdata.dbo.Event 
INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Tenants 
    ON taclogdata.dbo.Event.Tenant = InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId
INNER JOIN InetDb.dbo.Individuals
    ON  InetDb.dbo.Tenants.TenantId = InetDb.dbo.Individuals.TenantNdx
WHERE taclogdata.dbo.Event.EventTime 
       BETWEEN '01/04/2014 16:00:00' AND '01/04/2014 16:00:59'
```

Comment: Update the result in the question

Comment: @joebegborg07:- you are using sometime InetDb.dbo.Individuals and inet.dbo.Individuals????? which one is correct? And same with InetDb.dbo.Tenants and inet.dbo.Tenants????? USE the correct qualifier name for table...and you are good to go

Comment: Thanks. Having a long day. The error i got now was that FirstName and LastName are Ambigous coloums

Comment: You have FirstName and LastName  in two different tables, thats why you are getting Ambigous  columns issue....So use one tablename   in select list tablename.  like this `SELECT tablename.FirstName, tablename.Lastname` in Select List